# Linkedin Member Profile Plugin not working for some profiles

Tags: linkedin-api

We have a webpage that shows members of a team and it includes references to everyone's LinkedIn profile. We have used the Member Profile Plugin to show a preview of the profile.

Now we have a new team member and for some reason the plugin does not show her profile.

The problem is reproducible on LinkedIn's own "Member Profile Plugin Generator" page. (Cannot post link as StackOverflow allows only 2 - use Google to find it.)

If you use the profile URL: https://ee.linkedin.com/in/stina-pentj%C3%A4rv-53945011b and press 'Get Code' then you will get the code but the preview will be empty. And if I use the code on our site, nothing is shown either.

However if you use this profile URL: https://ee.linkedin.com/pub/kevin-schultz/96/59b/a16 and press 'Get Code' then you will immediately see the preview.

The profile URLs have different structure but that's what LinkedIn gives as public profile URLs. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you force the urls to match formats? Or generate a vanity URL for a profile that isnt working, to see if that fixes anything? I am having a similar issue where, even if the URLs are the same format, the tool only works for some profiles. I can see a preview for {LinkedIn big wig vanity URL}, but I see no preview for {random peon vanity URL}. The issue does not seem to correlate with whether or not the user has the "PREMIUM" text at the top of their page.

Comment: Hey it seems they have finally fixed it now, it works for me, whatever the profile