# Linkedin member profile request failing

Tags: plugins, linkedin-api, linkedin-plugins

I need to use the member profile plugin from LinkedIn for a project. So I generated my personal "code" at https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile . Which gives me the following standard code sample

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/myname" data-format="inline"></script>
```

Where "myname" is obviously replaced with the name at which my public LinkedIn profile is found.

My problem is that there is nothing showing, after inspecting the resulting html at a couple of frames deep there is only a hidden div with the following content:

```
<h2>
  Your Request Could not be Completed.
</h2>
```

I have checked all my privacy settings on LinkedIn and they are configured to make sure all information is publicly available and there should be no reason to let this plugin fail. I even checked with a colleague and we compared settings, the settings were the same but his plugin worked and mine did not.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem? Is there a setting we are missing, which is detrimental to this plugin?

(fyi, the plugin is running from a server so there is no problem to actually get the script)

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked several times here (as the LinkedIn support is unwilling to help and redirect here where developers seldom answer questions)

See this question
[Linkedin Member Profile Plugin not working for some profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885142/linkedin-member-profile-plugin-not-working-for-some-profiles/37031569#37031569)

One month after it was asked (yes one month!!!), a LinkedIn dev answered: 
"The problem is under investigation. Several profiles still work fine, so there isn't a systemic issue with the plugin itself, but rather with certain profiles in particular."

Note that the number of particular profiles seem to be huge, because 9 out of 10 profiles I try fail.

Nothing has changed since then...

This is not the only bug in LinkedIn which is litteraly ruining my experience with it. 
I used to love LinkedIn, but the way their support is treating customers (yes I am not only a user but also a customer because I pay for ads...) + the fact that they just can't seem to detect/fix their bug is making me become very bitter about them.

So all you can do is to cross fingers and hope that somewhere, someone will finally care about this and fix the bug...

Comment: I hope they might look into it, seeing as this still a bug somewhere! anyway thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Hey you should try again, it seems it is fixed now